# Удаление чекбоксов при нажатии на кнопку js

Tags: javascript

```
<div clas="dropdown-metro" id="dropdown-metro1">
    <div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
    <input name="subway" id="metro-32" type="checkbox" value="32" title="Приморская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Приморская')">
    <label for="metro-32">Приморская</label></div>

    <div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
    <input name="subway" id="metro-33" type="checkbox" value="33" title="Пролетарская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Пролетарская')">
    <label for="metro-33">Пролетарская</label></div>

</div>

<div class="panel-button">
    <button type="reset" onclick="merodivDel()">Сбросить</button> // При клике на кнопку должна сработать фунция удаления всех выделенных checkbox ТОЛЬКО В ПОЛЕ id="dropdown-metro1" и удалятся поля id="merodiv" так как выделинных чекбоксов  может быть несколько в id=" dropdown-metro1"
</div>

<div id="merodiv">
<div class="panel-tag" id="Пролетарская">Пролетарская<i data-value="Пролетарская" onclick="deleTe(this)">×</i> // При клике на onclick="metro_click('Приморская')" появляется данная строка
</div>
</div>

<script>
function merodivDel(){


}
</script>
```

Comment: ... и здесь надо всем все понять.

Comment: удаление или галочку снять? ничего не понятно..

Comment: Галочку снять, сорри

Comment: исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С удалением чекбоксов:

```js
function merodivDel(){
  document.getElementById('merodiv').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('dropdown-metro1').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div clas="dropdown-metro" id="dropdown-metro1">
    <div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
    <input name="subway" id="metro-32" type="checkbox" value="32" title="Приморская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Приморская')">
    <label for="metro-32">Приморская</label></div>

    <div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
    <input name="subway" id="metro-33" type="checkbox" value="33" title="Пролетарская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Пролетарская')">
    <label for="metro-33">Пролетарская</label></div>

</div>

<div class="panel-button">
    <button type="reset" onclick="merodivDel()">Сбросить</button> 
</div>

<div id="merodiv">
<div class="panel-tag" id="Пролетарская">Пролетарская<i data-value="Пролетарская" onclick="deleTe(this)">×</i>
</div>
</div>
```

С деактивацией чекбексов:

```js
function merodivDel(){
  document.getElementById('merodiv').innerHTML = '';
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById('dropdown-metro1').getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].type=='checkbox') {
          checkboxes[i].checked = false;
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div clas="dropdown-metro" id="dropdown-metro1">
    <div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
    <input name="subway" id="metro-32" type="checkbox" value="32" title="Приморская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Приморская')">
    <label for="metro-32">Приморская</label></div>

    <div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
    <input name="subway" id="metro-33" type="checkbox" value="33" title="Пролетарская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Пролетарская')">
    <label for="metro-33">Пролетарская</label></div>

</div>

<div class="panel-button">
    <button type="reset" onclick="merodivDel()">Сбросить</button> 
</div>

<div id="merodiv">
<div class="panel-tag" id="Пролетарская">Пролетарская<i data-value="Пролетарская" onclick="deleTe(this)">×</i>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div clas="dropdown-metro" id="dropdown-metro1">
    <div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
    <input name="subway" id="metro-32" type="checkbox" value="32" title="Приморская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Приморская')">
    <label for="metro-32">Приморская</label></div>

    <div class="dropdown-checkbox checkbox" id="metro_all">
    <input name="subway" id="metro-33" type="checkbox" value="33" title="Пролетарская" class="panel-checkbox" onclick="metro_click('Пролетарская')">
    <label for="metro-33">Пролетарская</label></div>

</div>

<div class="panel-button">
    <button type="reset" onclick="merodivDel()">Сбросить</button> // При клике на кнопку должна сработать фунция удаления всех выделенных checkbox ТОЛЬКО В ПОЛЕ id="dropdown-metro1" и удалятся поля id="merodiv" так как выделинных чекбоксов  может быть несколько в id=" dropdown-metro1"
</div>

<div id="merodiv">
<div class="panel-tag" id="Пролетарская">Пролетарская<i data-value="Пролетарская" onclick="deleTe(this)">×</i> // При клике на onclick="metro_click('Приморская')" появляется данная строка
</div>
</div>

<script>
function merodivDel(){
   var checkboxList = document.getEmelentsByClassName('panel-checkbox');
   var i = checkboxList.length;
   while (i--) {
      if (checkboxList[i].type=='checkbox') {
         checkboxList[i].checked = false;
      }
   }
}
</script>
```